# Home Assistant Mosquitto - What can I use as MQTT broker address?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, home-assistant

I'm using Home Assistant OS as a Virtualbox in Windows 10. I'm accessing it via homeassistant.local:8123. So I'm trying to configure my Mosquitto broker in Home Assistant. It wants to know my broker address. I'm guessing I need to use an ip. Where do I find this? Should I use localhost, 127.0.0.1, homeassistant.local or maybe an unused ip like 192.168.1.99 from my router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are following this [page](https://www.home-assistant.io/docs/mqtt/broker/), I find it is a bit misleading. Hope the following steps help you.

- **Install mosquitto (broker)**

  Suggest follow official github [doc](https://github.com/home-assistant/addons/blob/master/mosquitto/DOCS.md) to configure mosquitto addon; (*This step doesn't require IP configure*)
- **Configure client integration within home assistant**

  Refer to [here](https://www.home-assistant.io/integrations/mqtt/) for your client integration, use `localhost` for your ha integration to connect your mosquitto broker;
- **Configure MQTT client outside home assistant**

  you need to find the exposed IP of your mosquitto broker, in your case, it shall be your VM's IP.

Comment: I need to access the MQTT server from an ESP32 Arduino inside the home network but outside of the localhost compauter where home assistant is located. So should I still use localhost?

Comment: It is about your vm's virtualbox network setting, for example, if using bridge driver and your home router uses dhcp, then your vm should be assigned an IP from your router, you can either check it out from your home router or vm. Your Esp32 also need to be assigned ip from the same router.